# Power automate - is there a way to bypass Send email with options?

Tags: email, power-automate

I am trying to work out a scenario where a mail should get triggered for every ListItem in a SharePoint List.

Sharepoint List as follows

ID    Name        Email 
1    JimC     Jim@gmail.com 
2    KimJ     Kim@gmail.com 
3    SimK     Sim@gmail.com

I have created a Power Automate workflow, which gets triggered based on a recurrence schedule.
When it does get triggered, it checks a SharePoint list, that contains a list of individuals. Flow is suppose to process each individual,

- trigger mail using "**Send email with options**".
- wait for response (Approve / Reject / Need some details)
- log the response received from the individual

But issue here is if a person doesn't respond, the flow gets stuck & doesn't send mail to next individual. Seems, that's how "Send email with options" behave.

Is there a way, where we can wait for few hours / days for response to arrive? Else process the next individual in the SharePoint list by sending an email using "Send email with options"?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout period and by

1. Add try scope and add the "send email with options" step inside this scope.
   [image]
2. Click 3 dots at the "send email with options" step.

[image]

3. Click Settings

[image]

4. In the Timeout, enter the timeout period in ISO 8601 format e.g. PT3H means that this step will be timeout in 3 hours.

[image]

5. Add the catch scope and set the configure run after.

[image]

6. Select timed out and failed and add any step that you would like to do after  timed out inside the catch scope.

[image]

Hope this help.